# Constructing tensors with arbitrary rank and dimension

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, tensors

How can I create a tensor with arbitrary rank n and m components in each dimension?
I am looking for a command in which I insert n and m and it spits out the corresponding tensor with random entries (say, with RandomReal[] for each entry). 
I can keep constructing such a tensor manually by

```
Table[RandomReal[],{i,1,m},{i,1,m},{i,1,m}]
```

for n=3 for example. But it is obviously cumbersome for larger n.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `RandomReal[]`? Note for instance `RandomReal[1, ConstantArray[m, n]]`...

Comment: Does it work with normal distribution as well? It gives me error for other distributions

Comment: You're supposed to use `RandomVariate[]` for arbitrary distributions. But, that wasn't your original question.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
rankTensor[ranks_] := 
   Module[{x}, Fold[Table[#1, #2] &, x, ranks] /. x :> RandomReal[]]
```

Then

```
In[19]:= rankTensor[{2, 3, 4}]

Out[20]= {{{0.604317, 0.417602}, {0.66135, 0.40658}, {0.34705, 
 0.830708}}, {{0.941604, 0.286638}, {0.330288, 0.176155}, {0.516489,
 0.395396}}, {{0.881244, 0.568469}, {0.4826, 0.13277}, {0.243761, 
 0.430784}}, {{0.484282, 0.947463}, {0.103702, 0.976415},
 {0.763732, 0.351482}}}
```

Comment: Gives 'itform' errors.